# Find some numbers in Matlab satisfying a bunch of inequalities

Tags: matlab

I want to find some numbers in Matlab (denominated below `p11,..., p119`) satisfying a bunch  of inequalities (specifically, 16 inequalities). I want Matlab to keep searching until it finds such numbers. I thought about using `while` as below but it does no work. What is wrong? How can I proceed?

```
clear
rng default
%% SOME INITIAL VALUES
p11=0.3;
p12=0.4;
p13=0.1;
p14=0.2;
p15=0.2;
p16=0.2;
p17=0.06;
p18=0.03;
p19=0.02;
p110=0.04;
p111=0.07;
p112=50;
p113=0.02;
p114=0.03;
p115=0.01;
p116=0.08;
p117=0.01;
p118=0.1;
p119=0.07;

while ... %CONDITION THAT SHOULD BE SATISFIED (16 CONDITIONS)
     ((p11<=(p15+p19+p110+p111+p115+p116+p117+p119))+...
     (p12<=(p16+p19+p112+p113+p115+p117+p118+p119))+...
     (p13<=(p17+p110+p112+p114+p116+p117+p118+p119))+...
     (p14<=(p18+p111+p113+p114+p115+p116+p118+p119))+...
     (p11+p12<=(p15+p19+p110+p111+p115+p116+p117+p119+...
              p16+p112+p113+p118))+...
     (p11+p13<=(p15+p19+p110+p111+p115+p116+p117+p119+...
              p17+p112+p114+p118))+...
     (p11+p14<=(p15+p19+p110+p111+p115+p116+p117+p119+...
              p18+p113+p114+p118))+...
     (p12+p13<=(p16+p19+p112+p113+p115+p117+p118+p119+...
              p17+p110+p114+p116))+...
     (p12+p14<=(p16+p19+p112+p113+p115+p117+p118+p119+...
              p18+p111+p114+p116))+...
     (p13+p14<=(p17+p110+p112+p114+p116+p117+p118+p119+...
              p18+p111+p113+p115))+...
     (p11+p12+p13<=(p15+p19+p110+p111+p115+p116+p117+p119+...
                  p16+p112+p113+p118+...
                  p17+p114))+...
     (p11+p12+p14<=(p15+p19+p110+p111+p115+p116+p117+p119+...
                  p16+p112+p113+p118+...
                  p18+p114))+...
     (p11+p13+p14<=(p15+p19+p110+p111+p115+p116+p117+p119+...
                  p17+p112+p114+p118+...
                  p18+p113))+...
     (p12+p13+p14<=(p16+p19+p112+p113+p115+p117+p118+p119+...
                  p17+p110+p114+p116+...
                  p18+p111))+...
     (p11+p12+p13+p14==1)+...
     (p15+p16+p17+p18+p19+p110+p111+p112+p113+p114+p115+p116+p117+p118+p119==1))~=15


     % IF THE CONDITION IS NOT SATISFIED KEEP SEARCHING BY GUESSING 
     % OTHER NUMBERS
     p11=unifrnd(0,1);
     p12=unifrnd(0,1);
     p13=unifrnd(0,1);
     p14=unifrnd(0,1);
     p15=unifrnd(0,1);
     p16=unifrnd(0,1);
     p17=unifrnd(0,1);
     p18=unifrnd(0,1);
     p19=unifrnd(0,1);
     p110=unifrnd(0,1);
     p111=unifrnd(0,1);
     p112=unifrnd(0,1);
     p113=unifrnd(0,1);
     p114=unifrnd(0,1);
     p115=unifrnd(0,1);
     p116=unifrnd(0,1);
     p117=unifrnd(0,1);
     p118=unifrnd(0,1);
     p119=unifrnd(0,1);
end
```

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Thanks Matt: I guess there should be solvers of systems of linear inequalities in Matlab, but I wanted to try a naive approach, so I thought about writing few lines iteratively guessing and checking a possible solution of the system of inequalities. I understand that such a process could go forever, but the code above does not even start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop will run while the condition is `true`.  If `false` it terminates.  Your test conditions is `while .... ~= 15`.  This is `false` as the initial guesses result in 15 out of 16 trues.  Since `15 ~= 15` is `false`, the `while` loop doesn't run.

One way to fix the issue is to change from `~=` to `==`.  This will run through and find a solution to that condition.

You could have seen this by creating a variable called `tests` and populated it like this:

```
tests = [(p11<=(p15+p19+p110+p111+p115+p116+p117+p119));...
... skipped a bunch of stuff ...
    (p15+p16+p17+p18+p19+p110+p111+p112+p113+p114+p115+p116+p117+p118+p119==1)];
sum(tests)

ans = 15
```

Or any other way of tracking that value.